# Wicket String Validator for an Object mapped Form Component

Tags: wicket, wicketstuff

I am using a Form component to edit values in an Object . I have mapped an object using a LoadableDetachableModel to  the form so that the value in the object is displayed on the form and updates are applied automatically.

```
final Form<Withdrawal> form = new Form<Withdrawal>("form",
                new CompoundPropertyModel<Withdrawal>(ldm)) {
.... }
```

However, I have a problem with adding validators to form component such as StringValidator to text fields. I have a "comment" field ( one of the fields in the Withdrawal Object).

Ideally I want to add it as :

```
TextField<Withdrawal> tf_comments = new TextField<Withdrawal>("comment");
tf_comments.add( new StringValidator.MaximumLengthValidator(255));
form.add( tf_comments);
```

But since I cannot add StringValidators to it because `StringValidator` for `TextField<Withdrawal>` is not defined. So I am using the below and getting value of the field and setting it to object manually.

```
    TextField<String> tf_comments = new TextField<String>("comment");
    tf_comments.add( new StringValidator.MaximumLengthValidator(255));
    form.add(tf_comments);
```

Is there a way to add a **Validator** directly on to `TextField<Withdrawal>`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your understanding of `TextField<Withdrawal>` with `CompoundPropertyModel` ist wrong: The CompoundPropertyModel is responsible for binding a property specified by the name via `PropertyModel` to the TextField.
So you do not need generic `StringValidator` objects for the TextField.

In Wicket 6.7:
    
        `TextField<Withdrawal> tf_comments = new TextField<Withdrawal>("comment");
        tf_comments.add(StringValidator.maximumLength(255));`

For Wicket 1.5 your code should work, at least I'm not getting any syntax errors.
You should have getter and setter for "comment" in the Withdrawal class.

Comment: I am using Wicket 1.4. I am getting following error 

**no suitable method found for add(StringValidator)
    method FormComponent.add(IValidator<Withdrawal>) is not applicable
      (actual argument StringValidator cannot be converted to IValidator<Withdrawal> by method invocation conversion)**

Comment: Can't say what is wrong with your setup: I just quickly tested the example on jetty with wicket 1.5 and it was working. Can you paste more of your code (e.x. Withdrawal class) pastebin?

Comment: You specified Wicket 1.5 in the tag, so I tested for this version.
For Wicket 1.4 use just TextField<String> tf_comments = new TextField<String>("comment"). This should do the trick.
Btw: Is there a particular reason that you are using an outdated wicket version?